# TypeError: a.button is not a function styled-components nextjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

This is a tough one to debug. I have a failing next build due to an error from a UI component library (that I am the author of) I am trying to debug the error. Any tips?

error is a.button is not a function

```
- wait compiling...
- event compiled client and server successfully in 227 ms (361 modules)
- error node_modules/layla-ui-library/dist/cjs/index.js (1:534) @ eval
- error TypeError: a.button is not a function
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/.../.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
```

Looking at the dist/cjs/index,js I can see what it is referring to, but how do I relate that to the error in the code?

```
 o = a.button(
    i ||
      (i = s(
        [
          "\n  height: ",
          ";\n  border-radius: 4px;\n  font-size: ",
          ";\n  width: auto;\n  background-color: ",
          ";\n  color: #000000;\n  cursor: pointer;\n  border: ",
          ";\n  background: ",
          ";\n",
        ],
        [
          "\n  height: ",
          ";\n  border-radius: 4px;\n  font-size: ",
          ";\n  width: auto;\n  background-color: ",
          ";\n  color: #000000;\n  cursor: pointer;\n  border: ",
          ";\n  background: ",
          ";\n",
        ]
      )),
    function (c) {
      return c.size ? l(c.size) : l("md");
    },
    function (c) {
      return c.size
        ? (function (c) {
            switch (c) {
              case "sm":
                return "10px";
              case "md":
              default:
                return "12px";
              case "lg":
                return "14px";
            }
          })(c.size)
        : "md";
    },
    function (c) {
      return c.color ? c.color : null;
    },
    function (c) {
      return c.transparent ? "none" : null;
    },
    function (c) {
      return c.transparent ? "none" : null;
    }
  ),
```

It may be to do with styling?

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import { getButtonFontSize, getButtonSize } from "../../utils/getSize.utils";

export interface StyledButtonProps {
  size?: "sm" | "md" | "lg";
  color: string | undefined;
  transparent?: "true" | "false";
}

export const StyledButton = styled.button<StyledButtonProps>`
  height: ${(props) =>
    props.size ? getButtonSize(props.size) : getButtonSize("md")};
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: ${(props) => (props.size ? getButtonFontSize(props.size) : "md")};
  width: auto;
  background-color: ${(props) => (props.color ? props.color : null)};
  color: #000000;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: ${(props) => (props.transparent === "true" ? "none" : null)};
  background: ${(props) => (props.transparent === "true" ? "none" : null)};
`;
```

The button component is here: https://github.com/RichEwin/layla-ui/tree/master/src/components/Button